# set cap length for concatenated string

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

EDIT: I'm having alot of trouble formatting this code for some reason please bear with me. Also i'm aware some code is missing. This is just one portion of the code.

I am simulating a batch load that is run nightly to do some load testing. The problem I face is that my auto-generated PK's exceed the columns datalength after 100 or so inserts. How would I cap off my Strings without violating the unique constraint while inserting around 20,000 rows per table. my goal is to get rid of the random strings due to a change in requirements.Below is the portion of code I'm having trouble with.

```
declare
  l_cnt integer := 0;
  t_cnt integer := 0;
  c_cnt integer := 0;
  f_cnt integer := 0;
  i     integer := 0;

  TYPE T_EMPL_NO IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  TAB_EMPL_NO   T_EMPL_NO;
  TAB_SEC_PK    T_EMPL_NO;
  TAB_THR_PK    T_EMPL_NO;
  TAB_FTH_PK    T_EMPL_NO;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('START LOAD TEST');

  LOOP
    i := i + 1;
    TAB_EMPL_NO(l_cnt) := 'JB'||i;
    TAB_SEC_PK(t_cnt)  := dbms_random.string('L',6);
    TAB_THR_PK(c_cnt)  := dbms_random.string('L',1);
    TAB_FTH_PK(f_cnt)  := dbms_random.string('L',20);

    Insert into AOMS.PARTS_MONTH_CLOSE(
      NAMES OF COLUMNS HERE
    ) Values (
      TAB_EMPL_NO(l_cnt),
      TAB_SEC_PK(t_cnt),
      TAB_THR_PK(c_cnt),
      TAB_FTH_PK(f_cnt)
    );

    l_cnt := l_cnt + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    EXIT WHEN l_cnt = 100; -- change to record count 22k
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line('P2ACCTMO :Rows inserted: ' || l_cnt);
END;
/
```

As a bonus If I wanted the script to run for an hour but not exceed the amount of records that insert during a loop how would I do that? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: This is kind of hard to answer since we don't know what your table looks like, nor what data is in it, nor what the primary key value is, nor what error is produced when your inserts start to fail, and the code you posted is so heavily edited that it's really hard to tell what it might be doing. Please edit your question and add some additional explanatory information. Thanks.

Comment: I understand. How about this then.How can I set a variable to such as 'x' to not be greater than 1000?

Comment: You code does not appear to concatenate any strings (before or after my edit) so I am failing to see what the issue is. It also appears to be the equivalent of a simple hierarchical query: `INSERT INTO AOMS.PARTS_MONTH_CLOSE SELECT 'JB' || LEVEL, dbms_random.string('L',6), dbms_random.string('L',1), dbms_random.string('L',20), ... FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100;`

Comment: Please create a minimal working example which demonstrates your problem as your code does not appear to bear much relation to the question you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

To define a numeric datatype with a given range (let's say 1 to 1000, for the sake of argument) you can use a [user-defined PL/SQL subtype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#i42580). To do this you'd use something like

```
SUBTYPE MY_ZERO_TO_1K_SUBTYPE IS NUMBER(4,0) RANGE 0..1000;
```

and then define variables of this subtype just as you would any other variable:

```
nLimited_number  MY_ZERO_TO1K_SUBTYPE;
```

You can set a variable of this type to 0, 1, 2, ..., 998, 999, 1000. However, if you set it to a negative value or a value greater than 1000 an `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error` exception will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest to go for SEQUENCES rather than using Random string
>   generation. In this way you wlll not face unique key violation and
>   also you can set the max seq limit to the datatype limit of the
>   column. Hope this information helps.